# Templates pdf for invoices with ReportLab

Tags: django, pdf, reportlab, invoices

I'm wondering myself if there's any template code for make invoices output in pdf with reportlab, I'm developing in Django a platform sales and I need to output some data with a invoice look, I tried further but I didn't find anything, anyone know some resources? I don't care if I need to use another library, of course, for python.

Regards!

**Edit:**

Finally I found a solution with this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-invoice if anyone is interested.

Regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are familiar with HTML/CSS, you can first generate an HTML invoice using django's template, and then use the [xhtml2pdf](https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf) package to convert it into PDF format.

The [xhtml2pdf](https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf) is based on top of Reportlab, html5lib and pyPdf. I've used it before, and it solved my problem.

Comment: Take a look at this project, uses reportlab: https://github.com/radzhome/fedex-commercial-invoice